# Is it possible to bind datatable to the ToolStripMenuItem?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip

I'm using ContextMenuStrip & i created the submenus under ContextMenuStrip at runtime. By adding object of ToolStripMenuItem class. 
I'm having one datatable from that table i want to populate my submenus by using id & name field from my datatable for my further processing of application.

Is it possible?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows) {
                cms.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem() {
                    Text = dr["Name"].ToString()
                });
            }
```

Comment: @Vale: thanks but i want to add more than one field. Is this possible?

Comment: @ Richa Do you mean field from DataRow? You can add multiple fields as Text property to ToolStripMenuItem like this: 'Text = dr["Name"].ToString() + "-" + dr["ID"].ToString()' Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Vale:no. i mean i want to bind name to the text property & id as a value member. is this possible?

Comment: @Richa There is no value member in ToolStripMenuItem.

Comment: @Vale: do you mean to say there is no solution on this issue? Isn't it?

Comment: @Richa I am saying that you don't know exactly what you want. You want to assign value member to ToolStripMenuItem which is not possible because that control is not meant to be used like that. I don't know what you want to achieve...

Comment: @Vale: My ContextMenustrip contains list of Groups from the table. And when user right click on the Xtragridview that time i populated my ContextMenuStrip items depending on the list of groups from my table. My Xtragridview contains list of contacts and i want to add selected contact from the Xtragridview to the selected group form ContextMenuStrip item. Now i know i can do that code by using name of the group from ToolStripMenuItem's text property. But i'm having id's for all that groups in my table. ----

Comment: @Vale:----And i want to store groupid in another table. Then i'm thinking that if i'm having group id then why should i use group name field for my all application working.and i don't want to show id to the user. so that's why i'm searching about value member for the ToolStripMenuItem. Because of that i can handle the extra load on the database which will required for backward searching of group id field depending on group name.

Comment: @Richa Well, I guess you will have to stick to the name, or find another solution than.

Comment: I think that you must do it it with name, and not id.

Comment: @Vale: I've done by using name but this process is too lengthy. Because in this case i've to find id from the name field & i think which is not good.

Comment: Maybe you should store id in ToolStripMenuItem.Name and name to ToolStripMenuItem.Text property, so user will only see text

Comment: @Vale: I'll check this & if i get my issue answer then i'll inform you.

Comment: @Vale: I've implemented as you told. And it works fine. Thanks.